# Is there any festival in hindu religion celebrating girl child and why girls have to fast most of the time?

Tags: belief, festivals, fasting, gender

A person raised a question that why in Hindu religion we have "boy" centered festivals but none for girls. For example in north India we have *bhai-duj* and *jhat puja* festival in which family worship to god for well being of "boy" child. *Bhai-duj* is similar to *rakshabandhan*.

In a reply I said that in *Navratri* we **worship** girl child. And *bhai-duj* and *rakshabandhan* is for the love and relationship of brother and sister. This is pointless of saying that boys are treated special on these occasions.

Then another question was raised that why women always fast, sometime for husband and sometime for child(example: jhat puja)??

I was not even able to reply to it.

So is there any festivals with "girls" at the center? And is there any occasion where man take fast for "girls", if not then why always girls take fast?

**The whole point of the discussion was that to come to a conclusion that Hindu religion do not treat both the genders equally and so is men centered religion.**

Comment: men also have to fast on many occasions. but they don't. That's why Hinduism gets name as male-centered - because women follow the rules and men don't.. so people mistakenly think that men don't have to follow rules.

Comment: secondly, the girl's fasts are not mandatory, they are ishta or kamya. Like donating to charity is not a must.. if u don't do it, you won't get sin. but if you do it, you'll get great rewards. same way, the above fasts are for girls who want their husbands to live long & happy. They are not required to do it if they don't want to.

Comment: It's true that women do fasting on some occasions for the benefit of her husband.   In South India we don't find women  fasting for the benefit of her brother.@Singh

Comment: Are men in societies following other religions fasting for their women?  Can you produce evidence please for the fasting by men in societies following other religions?@Singh

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Sir, 'chhath puja' and 'bhai-duj' are festivals mainly celebrated in the state of Uttar Pradesh, Bihar and Jharkhand.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Sir the question was raised on the Hindu system of beliefs and so there is no point of comparing. Because then at last this will be concluded that all religions discriminate. But I belief that its not true for Hindu religion but I don't have any evidence.

Comment: No one  should not categorise a society as a whole,  based on some customs followed by some people. It is not a matured way of thinking.   Many Hindu men,  though not fast on any occasion,  will be caring for their families to the most .  We should see the way of life in toto but not customs being followed. @Singh

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Sir you are absolutely right, intention is more important than action. But nowadays it is becoming fashion to raise "stupid" questions on Hindu beliefs. Best example is Sabarimala temple, people who were raising questions on gender discrimination in temple were not worshipers of lord Ayyappa, those people just wanted to create disbelieve in youngsters. 
This is not a time to ignore stupid questions instead we need to stand and reply on there face.
This is my fault that I don't have enough knowledge to justify my believe system.